# How can I generate a GA tracking code programmatically?

Tags: google-analytics

How to generate Google Analytics tracking code programmatic-ally?

I am new to Google Analytics API, can someone please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is **NOT** possible to create new Google Analytics accounts or profiles programmatically using the existing APIs.

There are two APIs available, the [Data Export API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html) and the [Management API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mgmt/home.html). However, they are bot read-only.

> With the Google Analytics [Data Export API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html), you can develop client applications to request data from an existing Analytics profile for an authorized user, and refine the results of the request using query parameters. Currently, the Data Export API supports **read-only access** to your Google Analytics data.

> Currently, the [Management API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mgmt/home.html) supports **read-only access** to five components of the Google Analytics Management system: Account data,Profile data, Web property data, Goal data, Advanced segments

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, please consider updating given that it is now possible: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1#account_provisioning

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it's finally possible in 2021 with alpha api.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/properties/create#authorization-scopes

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to create Google Analytics accounts automatically at the moment but generating the tracking code is possible.

The only real variation between the tracking code generated each time you create a profile for a new domain is the web property ID. This is in the format `UA-XXXXXXX-X`. Each `X` is a number - the first 7 numbers are the account number and the number after the last dash relates to each web property set up for the account.

You can use the `accounts` feed of the API to get a list of accounts and their profiles. If an account only has one profile then it's possible to use the web property ID of it to automatically generate the tracking code. However, if there's multiple web properties then you would need a way to decide which one to use (present the user with a selection list etc).

Comment: So, how do you generate this tracking code ? I tried to use UA-XXXXXXX-2 instead of the existing UA-XXXXXXX-1, I get no error, but nothing appears on my GA management console. Do we have to ask the API to create the web property id ?