# Creating analytics property id using Piwik APIs

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, matomo, web-analytics-tools

I have an application, which creates web properties (Website, Apps) on the fly and I was wondering, If for these web properties, there is any way to generate property ID for tracking website Analytics, so that I can add tracking code when a property is created.

I was thinking of doing it programmatically using [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) API but found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455041/how-can-i-generate-a-ga-tracking-code-programmatically) that currently Google Analytics only provides read-only APIs, which does Not let user write anything on the account.

I know [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) is another very powerful tool that can be used for Analytics but Not very sure if Piwik provides this functionality and If not, How It can be customized for above needs.

**Question:**
Is there any way to achieve above functionality in Piwik or If not, can we customize Piwik for that requirement?

Comment: @Eduardo, I just modified the question.

Answer (score 1):

Piwiki is an open source tool that you install in your own servers. So technically you could do it any way by hacking into it.

But it also offers an API for creating and managing sites.

http://piwik.org/docs/analytics-api/reference/#SitesManager

Comment: Hi Eduardo, Thanks for your reply. Yeah, it's possible to customize Piwik that way but as this might take some time for me. I was thinking, If I can use Google Analytics for now to achieve functionality I mentioned above. In that case do you think, I can use custom variable to pass identifier for each domain and maintain everything under single property? or there are better ways to do it?

Comment: That was not the question.

Comment: Yeah Correct, I am asking If we can do that?